# Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express Various Problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Every time I launch Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express, I get this message:

[image]

The package that it gives can be different though.
In addition to that, if I try and load a project, solution, or make a new one, VS instantly crashes.

I tried re-installing Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express and it didn't help. Is there something VS is relying on that I should try re-installing?

Comment: Did you try to remove your recently installed extensions?

Comment: You may try to download the installation package again from MS? It may be possible that the installation package you are using is corrupted somehow.

Comment: This is usually caused by trouble with the registry on the machine.  Or other programs interfering with the way VS uses the registry, stuff like anti-virus programs.  You'll need to get your machine stable again.

Comment: 1. I have never consciously installed an extension. 2. I downloaded it when I re-installed it didn't I? 3. How can I "get my machine stable"?